# How can I make a script that opens terminal and runs my executable?

Tags: terminal

My students and I are using gcc to compile programs which ask a series of questions then display a result.  Right now if we are running a program called "main" for example, we have to open a terminal window then type:
./Programs/main

We would like to be able to distribute these to other students who don't know how to use the terminal, so that they can just double-click on a file.

I have tried to create a .command or .sh file that does this, but they will do "exit;" before the program can get input.  I also tried to use Automator, but this also exits before the program can get input.

Comment: Does the superuser answer work for you? http://superuser.com/questions/261194/how-can-i-execute-a-shell-script-without-exit-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

When you double-click a `.command` file, Terminal.app will open, and execute `/path/to/file.command ; exit;` which means it will execute the content of the `file.command` script, and THEN exit.

If your Terminal is exiting before your executable can receive input, that seems to indicate that either your `.command` is not calling your executable correctly, or your executable somehow doesn't wait to receive input before exiting.

To be able to help you further, you'd need to provide an example .c/.cpp file to compile, and the content of your `.command` file.

I myself tried with a `.command` file that contains only:

```
$HOME/Downloads/go.sh
```

And I was able to ask for input in `go.sh` (using `read -p`) before the Terminal exited.

Answer (score -1):

Add a "sleep" command to pause the script's execution.

```
Sleep 5
```

Will pause for 5 seconds.